# Is my fork suitable for my wheel

Tags: wheels, fork, compatibility, through-axle

I bought this front wheel
https://www.probikeshop.fr/roue-avant-mavic-aksium-ust-disc-a-pneus-center-lock-2-aa9/154559.html

and this surly fork
https://www.bike-components.de/fr/Surly/Fourche-Rigide-Straggler-Disc-28-700c-p38261/

and I would like to know if I can buy this front thru-axle (12mm diameter) to assemble these three components.

https://www.bike-components.de/en/Surly/Front-Thru-Axle-p75526/?o=69407947-black-15-x-110-mm

and we can read that:
"The Surly front thru-axle is suitable for Surly thru-axle compatible frames and does not destroy the look of the beautiful frames due to the low profile."
so I guess my fork is not compatible with my wheel ...

Comment: It'd be easier to know if these parts are compatible if you linked to their product pages at their respective manufacturer's websites. I, for one, can't distinguish 100 mm from 110 mm hubs in photos. For instance the thru-axel can be found here: https://surlybikes.com/parts/thru_axles It has a list of fork with which it'll work. If this in one of those forks, we're on our way.

Comment: @PaulH if a fork had 110mm spacing, I'm pretty sure it's a Boost fork. I assume that quick releases were dead on the MTB side some time before Boost was even established.

Comment: @WeiwenNg you're absolutely right, but that thru-axle sounds like it's meant to adapt thru-axle wheels to QR forks. It's a bad example, but my point is that specs are more useful that pictures here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't read French, but it is clear that the Mavic Aksium wheel you linked to has thru axle fittings: it stated that it took a 12x100mm front axle and a 12x142mm rear.

The Surly Straggler fork you linked to is for quick releases only. I believe this line:

> Système d'axe : réglage rapide (9 x 100 mm)

Was saying that the fork used quick releases. For sure, 9x100mm refers to quick releases. There are no thru axles with 9mm diameter. Also, the dropouts in the fork have openings at the bottom, to let you drop a quick release wheel out. TAs need to screw into a hole on one side of the fork, so TA forks have closed dropouts.

On Surly's website at least, one easy way to tell if the fork is for thru axles is that they picture it with a thru axle screwed in, e.g. this pic of the [Trucker fork](https://surlybikes.com/parts/disc_trucker_thru_axle_fork): (note, link goes to the US website)

[image]

It's also worth mentioning that the Straggler fork you linked to was for International Standard (IS, usually called post mount) disc brakes. Current drop bar bikes use the flat mount standard, although some older ones (around 2014-2016, I think) may have been for post mount brakes. Just make sure the brake system is correct for the rest of your components.

Comment: I do agree and my point is then to use an adaptator so that I put a quick release of 9x100mm. Is it suitable if I use disk brake system (indeed I have an adaptator from IS to PM, .... lot of adaptators) ? because I heard that thru axle was needed if one uses disk brake system for rigidity issue and I don't think an adaptator solves the rigidity issue, does it ?
NB: you can choose the language of the website.

Comment: Disk brakes have been used with QR axles for a long time. They have their problems, but it's not like they're going to kill you right now. The Surly fork is going to be heavy and flexy, through axle or not. I don't read French either, but Google Translate says the wheels come with adapters for 9mm QR axle in front and 135mm/10mm in rear.

Comment: @Smilia—I understand that you can use a though-axle/quick-release adapter, but you lose the benefits of a through-axle in that case (better rigidity, more precise disc rotor placement). The through axle you linked to in your question will not work with the adapter. You need a regular quick-release skewer for that, and for your fork.

Comment: Cycling snobbery is real. Through axle debates prove it. Disk brakes were in use for over decade before though axles widely replaced QR's.  The problems of QR+Disc are overstated. The advantages of though axles are real but also overstated.